# String Comparison Using Nested Loops

Tags: java, loops, comparison, string-comparison

I'm following this online Java course, after every session there is few assignments, and I can't seem to solve this one.

I know that's not the point of an exercise, but I tried everything and I can't see any other way.

---

Write a program that returns number of occurrences of a string in another string. For example:

**Input:**
First String: the

Second String: **the** students are working hard in **the** faculty of Engineering because **the**y love it

**Output:**
3

Note: You should use nested loops. Don’t use some methods like indexOf or substring

---

This is my code so far, I know it's not complete, and I'm pretty sure most of this decisions statements aren't needed.

Edit: This is a C# code, I was testing on both Java and C#

```
        String Text1 = Console.ReadLine();
        String Text2 = Console.ReadLine();
        int counter = 0;

        for (int y = 0; y < Text1.Length; y++)
        {

            for (int x = 0; x < Text2.Length; x++)
            {

                if (Text1[y] == Text2[x])
                {

                    if (y + 1 < Text1.Length && x + 1 < Text2.Length)
                    {
                        if (Text1[y + 1] == Text2[x + 1])
                        {

                        }
                    }


                }

            }

        }
```

Comment: @devnull this problem is not related to compare `String`s at all.

Comment: @devnull No, this isn't a duplicate of that famous question.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Too fast I guess.  Retracting.

Comment: You're following online Java course or C# course? Because it looks like C# for me...

Comment: erm.. the posted code is actually not a java code? `Text1.Length` looks more like C#

Comment: Yes it's a C# code sorry, I was testing on both. The syntax doesn't really matter I'm stuck with the logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are working on an exercise, I wouldn't fix your code, but help you fix it yourself.

First, some basics: in Java you use `charAt(i)` to access an individual character. For example,

```
char ch = Text1.charAt(3);
```

gets you the forth character from the beginning of the string (indexes are zero-based).

Now for the algorithm: you want to iterate through all positions of the second string with enough characters after it to make a match with the first string possible. This means that the index goes from zero, inclusive, to the position `Text2.length()-Text1.length()`, exclusive. This is the starting position of the potential match - let's call it `p`.

Given a position `p`, you want to iterate through all characters of `Text1` starting at zero, and compare them to `Text2` characters starting with the character at position `p`. Let's say the index in `Text1` is called `i`, and it goes from zero, inclusive, to `Text1.length()`, exclusive. Then you want to compare `Text1.getChar(i)` for equality with `Text1.charAt(i+p)`.

You need to finish the comparison with all characters of `Text1` before you declare a match. You need to know the result in the outer loop, so you want to use a `bool` flag. Set the flag to `true` before the inner loop. If you see a mismatch, set the flag to `false`, and break out of the loop.

If the flag is `true` after the inner loop, increment the counter.

Comment: Thanks a lot, most of this makes sense but bare with me here I honestly don't understand why position P is so important and why I have to do Text1.charAt(i+P) , sorry but it's a bit confusing.

Comment: @Mody Think about it this way: imagine that `Text1` and `Text2` are written on tapes of paper. To find all matches, you would align the tape `Text1` with `Text2` at the initial position, and then go through the pairs of letters one by one to see if they match. Then you would move the `Text1` tape by one character, so its initial character is aligned with the second character of `Text2`, and repeat the match process. Then you would move to character three, four, and so on. `p` represents the character of `Text2` with which the initial character of `Text1` is aligned when you check the match.

Comment: Sorry it took me so long, but I got it now thanks a lot. That wasn't an easy task though :)

Answer (score 1):

```
public static int count(String text1, String text2)
{
    int res = 0;
    for (int i=0;i<text2.length()-text1.length();i++)
    {
       if (text1.charAt(0) == text2.charAt(i))
       {
          boolean found = true;
          for (int j=0;j<text1.length() && found;j++)
              if (text1.charAt(j) != text2.charAt(i+j))
                  found = false;
          if (found)
              res++;
       }
    }
    return res;
}
```

Comment: Your code worked just fine however I couldn't understand why it did, but dasblinkenlight did the explaining, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

@Mody- As this is an assignment, I suggest you to follow "public int indexOf(String str)" method in String.class and replicate something similar with little modification to solve your problem.

Comment: If you need help in coding, then plz first take attempts from your side and later we could help you with code.

Comment: The best way to learn Java is to chase the predefined classes in it.

Comment: I will try that, I did a lot of attempts for days now but the problem is I couldn't find the right approach for this problem, I did similar tasks and it was fine. Thanks